Error 404 when trying to edit page with imported template in Elementor (WordPress)
I just bought a domain and WordPress hosting, along with some .ZIP templates for landing pages to import into the site. The import works, and I can see and edit the template in Elementor (free). I publish the page, and it goes online with the imported template. The problem occurs when I leave the editing page and try to edit again with Elementor: it says that the page was not found. This happens with literally all the templates I bought. What I have already tested: updating Elementor, deleting plugins, importing templates in different ways, changing the theme, and nothing works.
Explanatory video: https://www.canva.com/design/DAGJP_8rZNc/UrSjU-QoWolis1btzASKvg/edit?utm_content=DAGJP_8rZNc&utm_campaign=designshare&utm_medium=link2&utm_source=sharebutton
Update plugins, kit import with different methods and change wordpress theme
